# Why kivy controls repeat in the widget?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I ran the code but the result is unexpected to me.
it displays the widget twice, in fact even more times. but I dont know why.
here is my code:

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

Builder.load_file('menu.kv')
class menu(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu().run()
```

.ky

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<MyWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical" 
    Button: 
        size_hint: 1, .25
        text: "1"
    Button: 
        size_hint: 1, .25
        text: "2"
    Button: 
        size_hint: 1, .25
        text: "3"
    Button: 
        size_hint: 1, .25
        text: "4"
```

and it shows in following:
[repeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDpMP.png)

thank you so much

Comment: What is the name of the .py and .kv files?

Comment: Thx a lot. One is named menu.py and another named menu.kv. It's really the problem named 'menu'. But why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you used both `Builder.load_file('menu.kv')` and `return MyWidget()`. You could omit either the 1st line mentioned or remove the `build(self)` method.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion. But it said error. I changed the name of file. And it worked normal now.

Answer (score 0):

After I tried, the name of the .py and .kv files caused the problem.

So I modified name of the file(ori name: menu.py, menu.kv).